# Need to pass node object created in loop to edges

Tags: javascript, json, graph, cytoscape

I am reading in and looping through a json file to create a graph with nodes and edges using a JavaScript library cytoscape, but am having some newbie problems. Here is my pseudo code w/pseudo bugs.

1) Create new node for each node with label 'x'

2) For each edge in edges, create edge with 'source', 'target'.

The problem that I am having is that to create the edge I need to pass each node object as the argument, (sourceNode, targetNode, {weight: 'y'} so something like this will not work

```
var edge = graph.newEdge({source: graphP.elements.edges[j].data.source},
                                 {target: graphP.elements.edges[j].data.target});
```

I tried creating an array and writing each new node to it, but I just end up over-writing the value of the variable name and end up with an array of length 1. While all my nodes are created, I need a way to go back and access the nodes in order to create the edges ( and obviously not have them point to themselves).

I am guessing it will be some sort of nodeObject.hasKey[label] and match on that label to retrieve node ID, then create new edge?

I've thought myself in a knot here. Any advice is appreciated. Below is my current code with abbreviated json file read in.

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Springy.js image node demo</title>
</head>
<body>
<script src="jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<script src="springy.js"></script>
<script src="springyui.js"></script>

<!--<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>-->

<script/>  
$(document).ready(function(){
  $.ajax({
    url: 'https://rawgit.com/theresajbecker/CompBio/master/SuperSmallNodes.json',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json'
  }).done(function(graphP) {  

    console.log(graphP);


    var graph = new Springy.Graph();

    for ( i = 0  ; i < graphP.elements.nodes.length ; i++ ) { 
        var nodeArray = []
        var Nlabel1 =  graphP.elements.nodes[i].data.label
        var Nlabel2 =  graphP.elements.nodes[i++].data.label
        console.log('Nlabel1')
        console.log(Nlabel1)
        console.log('Nlabel2')
        console.log(Nlabel2)
        var NN1 = graph.newNode({label: Nlabel1})
        var NN2 = graph.newNode({label: Nlabel2})
        nodeArray.push(NN1)
        nodeArray.push(NN2)
        graph.newEdge(NN1,NN2, {weight: .5})

                                                 }
    console.log('NODE ARRAY')
    console.log(nodeArray)  



        console.log('WINDOW')
jQuery(function(){
  var springy = window.springy = jQuery('#springydemo').springy({
    graph: graph,
    nodeSelected: function(node){
      console.log('Node selected: ' + JSON.stringify(node.data));
    }
  });
});

    });  


});
</script>
    <div>
<canvas id="springydemo" width="800" height="400" style="border: 1px solid black;"></canvas>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

At minimum, I would think you'd want to initialize nodeArray outside of the loop:

```
var nodeArray = []
for ( i = 0  ; i < graphP.elements.nodes.length ; i++ ) {
```

As is, the re-initialization in each loop would explain the length of 1.

Answer (score 0):

I apparently got so focused on other problems that I didn't see that I was initializing my array inside the loop. Genius. However, for reference, here is how I was able to pass the sourceNode and targetNode objects to the newEdge function.

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Springy.js image node demo</title>
</head>
<body>
<script src="jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<script src="springy.js"></script>
<script src="springyui.js"></script>

<!--<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>-->

<script/>  
$(document).ready(function(){
  $.ajax({
    url: 'https://rawgit.com/theresajbecker/CompBio/master/SuperSmallNodes.json',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json'
  }).done(function(graphP) {  

    console.log(graphP);


    var graph = new Springy.Graph();
    var nodeArray = []

    for ( i = 0  ; i < graphP.elements.nodes.length ; i++ ) { 
        var Nlabel1 =  graphP.elements.nodes[i].data.label
        var Nmass =  graphP.elements.nodes[i].data.mass

        var NN1 = graph.newNode({label: Nlabel1}, {'text-outline-width': Nmass});
        nodeArray.push(NN1)
        }
        console.log(nodeArray)

        function getByValue(arr, value) {
          for (var n=0; n < nodeArray.length; n++) {
            if (arr[n].data.label == value) {
            console.log("below should be the object of element")
            return arr[n];
            }
          }
        }


        function getSourceNode(graphP) {
          for (var s=0; s < graphP.elements.edges.length; s++) {
            var getSource = graphP.elements.edges[s].data.source
            var getTarget = graphP.elements.edges[s].data.target
            graph.newEdge(getByValue(nodeArray, getSource),getByValue(nodeArray, getTarget));

        }
        }

    getSourceNode(graphP)


        console.log('WINDOW')
jQuery(function(){
  var springy = window.springy = jQuery('#springydemo').springy({
    graph: graph,
    nodeSelected: function(node){
      console.log('Node selected: ' + JSON.stringify(node.data));
    }
  });
}); 

    });  


});
</script>
    <div>
<canvas id="springydemo" width="800" height="400" style="border: 1px solid black;"></canvas>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```